# inheriting xdocument/xelement namespace issues (google contacts api)

Tags: .net, xml, namespaces, linq-to-xml

im trying to parse the XML returned by Google contacts API

i made some helper classes to give me strongly-typed access to the necessary data, but cant seem to be making them work in tandem.

i made a class GoogleDocument which inherits XDocument and a GoogleContact which inherits XElement

```
Class GoogleDocument
Inherits XDocument
Dim xnsAtom = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
Sub New()
    MyBase.new()
End Sub
Sub New(other As XDocument)
    MyBase.New(other)
End Sub
ReadOnly Property Entries As IEnumerable(Of GoogleContact)
    Get
        Dim feed = Element(xnsAtom + "feed")
        Dim ret = New List(Of GoogleContact)
        For Each e In feed.Elements(xnsAtom + "entry")
            ret.Add(New GoogleContact(e))
        Next
        Return ret.AsEnumerable
    End Get
End Property
End Class

Class GoogleContact
Inherits XElement
Dim xnsGd = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.google.com/g/2005")
Dim xnsAtom = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
Dim xnsApp = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2007/app")
Sub New(other As XElement)
    MyBase.new(other)
End Sub
ReadOnly Property ETag As String
    Get
        Return Attribute(xnsGd + "etag").Value
    End Get
End Property
ReadOnly Property ContactID As Integer
    Get
        Dim uri = Element(xnsAtom + "id").Value
        Return uri.Substring(uri.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)
    End Get
End Property
ReadOnly Property Edited As DateTime
    Get
        Return Date.Parse(Element(xnsApp + "edited").Value)
    End Get
End Property
End Class
```

questions:

1. isn't there an easier way to convert all matching elements to GoogleContacts? then adding each 1 via iteration. also it seems that GoogleContact is not really an XElement as in the debugger it shows up as `{<entry....>}` instead of `<entry....>` im not sure what these braces mean here, but its odd
2. why do i need to declare the namespaces again and again? isn't there a way to somehow pass over to GoogleContact all relevant namespaces? the way its now, Google refuses to accept the data back as all namespaces become "p1"

i'd appreciate any advice on the subject

thank you very much

**EDIT**

here's a more complete code sample, with changes per Jon Skeet's suggestions

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Module1

Dim GUserName As String
Dim GPassword As String
Sub Main()
    Dim authRequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin")
    authRequest.KeepAlive = True
    authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    authRequest.Method = "POST"
    Dim encoder = New ASCIIEncoding
    Dim encodedData = encoder.GetBytes("Email=" & GUserName & "&Passwd=" & GPassword & "&source=Consultor&service=cp&accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE")
    authRequest.ContentLength = encodedData.Length
    Dim requestStream = authRequest.GetRequestStream
    requestStream.Write(encodedData, 0, encodedData.Length)
    requestStream.Close()
    Dim authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse
    Dim readStream = New StreamReader(authResponse.GetResponseStream, encoder)
    Dim body = readStream.ReadToEnd
    Dim tokens = TextCollection(body, "=", Chr(10))
    Dim req2 = New GoogleClient(tokens("auth"))
    body = req2.GetString("default/full?max-results=5000")
    Dim gDoc = New GoogleDocument(XDocument.Parse(body))
    Dim dcx = DBEntities()
    Dim pers = dcx.Persons
    For Each ge In gDoc.Entries
        Dim entry = ge
        Dim id As String = entry.ContactID
        Dim p As Object '= (From x In pers Where x.GoogleCode = id).FirstOrDefault' cant ompile iin this demo
        If p Is Nothing Then Exit For
        If entry.Edited > p.LastEdit Then
            p.GoogleCode = entry.ContactID
            dcx.SaveChanges()
        Else
            Dim updClient = New GoogleClient(tokens("auth"))
            updClient.ETag = entry.ETag
            Dim updResp = updClient.PutString("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/" & GUserName & "/base/" & entry.ContactID, entry.UpdateXml)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Class GoogleClient
    Inherits WebClient
    Property ETag As String

    Const UrlStart = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/"
    Sub New(AuthToken As String)
        Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8")
        Headers.Add("User-Agent", "G-Consultor/GDataGAuthRequestFactory-CS-Version=1.9.0.23118--IEnumerable")
        Headers.Add("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" & AuthToken)
        Headers.Add("GData-Version", "3.0")
    End Sub
    Function GetString(Path As String) As String
        Return DownloadString(UrlStart & Path)
    End Function
    Public Function PutString(address As String, data As String) As String
        If ETag <> "" Then
            Headers.Add("Etag", ETag)
            Headers.Add("If-Match", ETag)
        End If
        Return UploadString(address, "PUT", data)
    End Function
End Class
Function TextCollection(Text As String, FieldDelimiter As String, Optional RowDelimiter As String = vbCrLf) As NameValueCollection
    Text = Text.RightCut(RowDelimiter)
    Dim ret = New NameValueCollection
    Dim rows = Text.Split(RowDelimiter)
    For Each cl In rows
        ret.Add(cl.Substring(0, cl.IndexOf(FieldDelimiter)), cl.Substring(cl.IndexOf(FieldDelimiter) + FieldDelimiter.Length))
    Next
    Return ret
End Function
Class GoogleDocument
    Inherits XDocument
    Dim xnsAtom = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
    Sub New()
        MyBase.new()
    End Sub
    Sub New(other As XDocument)
        MyBase.New(other)
    End Sub
    ReadOnly Property Entries As IEnumerable(Of GoogleContact)
        Get
            Dim feed = Element(xnsAtom + "feed")
            Dim ret = New List(Of GoogleContact)
            For Each e In feed.Elements(xnsAtom + "entry")
                ret.Add(New GoogleContact(e))
            Next
            Return ret.AsEnumerable
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
Function DBEntities() As Object 'really should return my EF data model
    Return Nothing
End Function
<Extension()> Function RightCut(value As String, CutString As String) As String
    If Right(value, CutString.Length) = CutString Then value = value.Substring(0, value.Length - CutString.Length)
    Return value
End Function
Class GoogleContact
    Dim xnsGd = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.google.com/g/2005")
    Dim xnsAtom = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
    Dim xnsApp = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2007/app")
    Dim xContact As XElement
    Sub New(entry As XElement)
        xContact = entry
    End Sub
    ReadOnly Property ETag As String
        Get
            Return xContact.Attribute(xnsGd + "etag").Value
        End Get
    End Property
    ReadOnly Property ContactID As Integer
        Get
            Dim uri = xContact.Element(xnsAtom + "id").Value
            Return uri.Substring(uri.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)
        End Get
    End Property
    ReadOnly Property Edited As DateTime
        Get
            Return Date.Parse(xContact.Element(xnsApp + "edited").Value)
        End Get
    End Property

    ReadOnly Property UpdateXml
        Get
            Return "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & xContact.ToString
        End Get
    End Property

    Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return xContact.ToString
    End Function
End Class
End Module
```

Comment: Why are you inheriting from XDocument and XElement? That sounds like a bad idea to me - why not just create classes which *compose* an existing object?

Comment: several reasons:initially because ive done so in the past for similar situations but without namespaces, and also its a natural fit for something that comes in as xml snippets. but moreover because in the end i sometimes need to call `ToString` to get the exact XML structure to post back to Google for updates

Comment: None of those sound like good reasons to me. A contact isn't naturally an XML element - that's just how it *may* be represented. You can always override `ToString()` (or create a separate method) to get the XML back.

Comment: i dont feel like rebuilding the whole xml in ToString,when i can just keep the original xml throughout the code, with just a few added properties

Comment: You wouldn't have to "rebuild" it all - you'd just call `ToString` on the member variable which still stored the `XElement`. The point would be to use *composition* instead of *inheritance*.

Comment: lets say i need to change the email address, now all i have to do is set the value of the node in the class' `Email` property `set` method. and when i call `ToString`, everything happens by itslef, as all values are in place.but im open to new ideas. what do you mean by _composition_?

Comment: I mean your `GoogleContact` class would have an `XElement` *field* rather than being an `XElement` itself. You'd still be able to do all the same things - but clients wouldn't be able to mess with your data by adding random child nodes to a `GoogleContact`.

Comment: ok. im trying your way now. but i still have the same basic problem. the snippets that i need to `PUT` back are not 100% the same as they come in. i have to add namespaces to them. so im back to square one. how do  i add a namespace to an existing `XElement` snippet?

Comment: Why aren't you *creating* the `XElement` with the right namespace to start with? You haven't shown where you're creating elements, as far as I can see.

Comment: it happens on line 15 in my code above `ret.Add(New GoogleContact(e))`. BTW, i really appreciate your guidance. please keep it up!

Comment: So presumably `e` is in the wrong namespace? This is the sort of problem I mean - you've got two elements involved: the one you're copying from, and the new one you're creating. It's much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: well there's nothing much i can do about the complications. that's how big G wills it. the issue is that the snippet that comes in for each entry doesn't have all namespaces in it, as they are declared up on top of the file. its up to us to somehow inject them into the snippet for re-PUT-ing  --THANKS!!

Comment: No, they should inherit the namespace defaulted at the start of the document. Just because they don't explicitly declare the namespace doesn't mean it's not part of the element name. It *should* all be fine.

Comment: hi. thanks for all your help.  i really appreciate. when i download the contacts i get 1 big file with many "entries", but when i want to update i send back only a certain entry, with the updated info. so the snippet in itself doesn't have all the namespace declarations in it, and i have to add them manually

Comment: When you load the file into an `XDocument`, it doesn't remember the *text* - it remembers the *full name* of the element. If you could show a short but *complete* program demonstrating what you're doing, that would be really helpful. (Also, have you tried the .NET API instead of doing all of this manually?)

Comment: OK, i posted now a pretty complete console app, with some minor changes because i didn't want to use my whole EF module.. and yes i have tried their dll's but didn't find them very helpful. also this is important for me as i once had similar issues with UPS namespaces. thanks

Comment: I'll take a look this afternoon. Will have to mentally translate from VB to C# first though :)

Comment: You've only *partially* used my suggestions - you're still overusing inheritance IMO. Anyway, that's probably irrelevant to the question. You still need to say what your example is *meant* to do, and what *actually* happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not entirely clear what's actually going *wrong* - if you specify the right namespace everywhere, it should all be fine. However, you don't need to repeat the names all over the place - you may well want to create shared readonly fields of type `XName` to avoid typos. I'd also use the implicit conversion from `String` to `XName` for simplicity. In C# I'd write this as something like:

```
private static readonly XNamespace AtomNs = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
private static readonly XNamespace GoogleDataNs =
    "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005";
private static readonly XNamespace AppNs = "http://www.w3.org/2007/app";

// You should work out where to put these, and their visibility
public static readonly XName FeedElementName = AtomNs + "feed";
public static readonly XName EntryElementName = AtomNs + "entry";
public static readonly XName ETagAttributeName = GoogleDataNs + "etag";
// etc
```

Then you can use those "constants" everywhere - it doesn't *matter* that they've got namespaces; that doesn't end up getting used within your code, because you're just referring to "the element name" or "the attribute name" appropriately.

In general terms, ways to improve your code:

- I'd still suggest using the .NET API if you can; you say you "didn't find them very helpful" but that may just mean that you didn't investigate them for long enough. Once you've got the hang of them, they're likely to save you time.
- I wouldn't use *any* inheritance in the code you've given - there's no need to derive from `WebClient`, `XDocument` or `XElement`. Your code will be clearer without the inheritance here, as you can create just the members which are relevant for the object you're try to model.
- You can use LINQ to query the `XDocument` and create a collection of contacts. For example (C# again, but VB would be similar):

  ```
  List<GoogleContact> = document.Root
             .Elements(GoogleContact.EntryElementName)
             .Select(element => new GoogleContact(element))
             .ToList();
  ```

Comment: ill ask you openly, at this point, as we might be very close to figuring it out, do u think i should drop all and try their dlls? i guess if u say so, ill go that way. i don't want to waste your time. but if i can have my own code do it, id appreciate it. i also appreciate the the `LINQ` u posted towards the end. about inheritance, i do like it that way, but i don't think its relevant. but all this does not help us inject them namespaces where necessary? what do u suggest? thanks for taking all this time and for your insight (PS. feel free to post in C#

Comment: @Yisman: Yes, you should absolutely spend a bit of time with the libraries that are designed to make this easier. And yes, the inheritance part is somewhat orthogonal to everything else, but I'd still strongly encourage you to think about it carefully (not just for here, but elsewhere).

Comment: ok, so for now ill accept your answer, while i try it out again. if it wont work out, we'll see then. thanks for all your work. your post count is definitely impressive!!